# Javascript combine multiple methods

Tags: javascript, regex, three.js

```
scene.remove(xaxis);
scene.remove(yaxis);
scene.remove(zaxis);
```

Is there a way to combine these into one single line (maybe using regex?). This is part of the three.js library.

Comment: [xaxis,yaxis,zaxis].map(scene.remove.bind(scene);

Comment: @dandavis You shouldn't use `map` when simply iterating over an array. `map` has a purpose, so does `forEach`

Comment: Why do you want it on a single line? What would you do with regex?

Comment: @Ian: what's the harm in using [].map() ?

Comment: @dandavis It does a lot more than necessary for this example, creates an unnecessary array (that is returned), and teaches others the wrong reason to use `map`. It's a good idea, I just think it should be `forEach` instead

Comment: @iamnotmaynard I just want to condense the code to make it less repetitive.

Comment: @ian: i think it's a stretch to coin it "a lot more" work. i bench about 2-5% on a good day... I started out back in the day with a shim for filter+map, which led me to recycle those a lot. I still use map because it's less to type and allows me to collect a return and because I try to use pure functions, which are typically useless in forEach... Occasionally, i'll go back and downgrade to forEach if perf is an issue...

Comment: @user1950278 if you want to avoid repetition, gion_13's answer is what you are looking for.

Comment: I was hoping that there would be one liner approach like in bash where you can do something like [xyz]axis with regex.

Comment: @dandavis Obviously performance isn't that big of an issue. I wouldn't be surprised if this backfired on me and `map` ended up being faster than `forEach`. So ignoring perf, it doesn't make sense semantically to me is all. `map` is meant to return a new array with the provided function called on each item. `forEach` is simply meant to iterate through all items. Since the OP really only needs to iterate, it just makes more sense to me to use `forEach`. It's really not that important - your code would clearly work, I'm just picky :(

Comment: @user1950278 even if that would be possible, using a function would still be the better approach, because it is less repetetive.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry if this isn't the answer you want, but what about wrapping them into a function?

```
function removeAxes(){
    scene.remove(xaxis);
    scene.remove(yaxis);
    scene.remove(zaxis);
}
```

Comment: Should be plural — `removeAxes()`. Otherwise I'd say this is the most sensible solution, unless there's a compelling reason to do it differently.

Answer (score 1):

Write this anywhere in your code.

```
THREE.Scene.prototype.removeItems = function(){

for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++)
this.remove(arguments[i])

}
```

Now the `Scene` object accepts all the arguments you want. You can condensate the 3 lines anywhere in your code...

```
scene.removeItems(xaxis, yaxis, zaxis);
```

... call it with any number of arguments...

```
scene.removeItems(someStuff, someOtherStuff);
```

... be it 1 or 100

```
scene.removeItems(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```